# Inserting footnote in google doc using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api, footnotes

I am automating the creation of a document using google apps script. This script runs in a google sheet and creates a document with text, tables, references, and so on. The document has approx. 10 pages and a section that is the same in every document.

After the word “Urgência” I want to insert a footnote index (with the number 1) and the respective text at the bottom of the page, something like this: “4.8 Urgência¹ (conforme definição….”

This is a snippet of the middle of my code:

```
     var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
     var id = doc.getId();
     var corpo = doc.getBody();

     var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("\n\n\n\n\nNota Técnica*" + "\n\n" + "Processo" + "\n" + numero_processo).setFontSize(30).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).setFontFamily("Lato");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("\nData de submissão: XX/XX/2022").setFontSize(14).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT).setFontFamily("Lato").setBold(true);
      // Cria uma página nova
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n*Avaliação técnica produzida no âmbito institucional do TelessaúdeRS-UFRGS, estabelecido como Núcleo de Apoio Técnico da Justiça Federal do Rio Grande do Sul (NAT-Jus/JFRS) pelo Contrato n° 33/2019 firmado pela JFRS, UFRGS e FAURGS. Elaboração por profissionais da saúde, baseada em evidências científicas de eficácia, acurácia, efetividade, segurança e custo-efetividade, conforme termos contratuais e o disposto na Resolução Nº 388/2021 do CNJ e no § 2º do art. 156 do CPC, Lei nº 13.105/2015").setFontSize(10).setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY).setFontFamily("Arial").setBold(false);
      corpo.appendPageBreak();

      // Adiciona item 1 do processo:
      var titulo = corpo.appendParagraph("1\tDados do processo");
      titulo.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setBold(true);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("1.1\tNúmero do Processo:  " + numero_processo);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("1.2\tVara: " + " " + vara);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");;

      // Adiciona item 2 do processo:
      var titulo = corpo.appendParagraph("2\tDados do Paciente");
      titulo.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setBold(true);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("2.1\tCartão Nacional da Saúde: " + cns);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("2.2\tCPF: " + cpf);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("2.3\tNome: " + nome_paciente);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("2.4\tData de Nascimento: " + data_nascimento);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("2.5\tIdade: " + idade);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("2.6\tSexo: " + sexo);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("2.7\tNome da mãe: " + nome_mae);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("2.8\tMunicípio de residência/UF: " + residencia);
     texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");

      // Adiciona item 3 do processo:
      var titulo = corpo.appendParagraph("3\tDados do Prescritor");
      titulo.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setBold(true);  
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("3.1\tUF do CRM: " + uf_crm);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("3.2\tNúmero de registro no Conselho Regional de Medicina: " + numero_crm);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("3.3\tNome do Médico: " + nome_medico);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");

      // Adiciona item 4 do processo:
      var titulo = corpo.appendParagraph("4\tDados da Prescrição");
      titulo.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setBold(true);  
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("4.1\tTipo: " + abaTecnologia.getRange(3, 2).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("4.2\tDenominação:  " + abaTecnologia.getRange(4, 2).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("4.3\tCID: " + cid_original);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("4.4\tPrescrição: " + prescricao);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("4.5\tMeio(s) confirmatório(s) do diagnóstico disponibilizado(s): ");
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("4.6\tCapacidade funcional do paciente (ECOG Performance Status): " + ecog);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("4.7\tPaciente internado: " + internado);
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial"); 

      // IN THIS ITEM I WOULD LIKE TO ADD THE FOOTNOTE
      var text = "4.8\tUrgência";
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph(text + " (conforme definição da Resolução CFM nº 1451/95: ocorrência imprevista de agravo à saúde com ou sem risco potencial de vida, cujo portador necessita de assistência médica imediata): " + urgencia);
texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");

      // Adiciona item 4.9
      var titulo = corpo.appendParagraph("4.9\tJustificativa para Prescrição").setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      titulo.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setBold(true);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("\nINSERIR HISTÓRIA CLÍNICA\n")
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph(abaTecnologia.getRange(8, 1).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      texto.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY)

      // Adiciona item 5 do processo:
      var titulo = corpo.appendParagraph("5\tDados da Tecnologia");
      titulo.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setBold(true);  
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("5.1\tRegistro na ANVISA: " + abaTecnologia.getRange(11, 2).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("5.2\tIndicação em conformidade com a aprovada no registro: " + abaTecnologia.getRange(12, 2).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("5.3\tExiste genérico ou similar: " + abaTecnologia.getRange(13, 2).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("5.4\tParecer da CONITEC: " + abaTecnologia.getRange(14, 2).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("5.5\tDisponível no SUS: " + abaTecnologia.getRange(15, 2).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("5.6\tPrevisto em Protocolo Clínico e Diretrizes Terapêuticas do Ministério da Saúde para a situação clínica do demandante: " + abaTecnologia.getRange(16, 2).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("5.7\tAlternativa disponível no SUS: " + abaTecnologia.getRange(17, 2).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY); 
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("5.8\tNegativa administrativa: " + negativa_administrativa);
texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY); 

      // Adiciona itens 6 do processo
      var titulo = corpo.appendParagraph("6\tParecer do Consultor/Perito");
      titulo.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setBold(true);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("6.1\tEfetividade, eficácia e segurança: \n" + abaTecnologia.getRange(21, 1).getValue() + "\n");
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("6.2\tBenefício/efeito/resultado esperado da tecnologia: " + abaTecnologia.getRange(22, 2).getValue() + "\n");
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("6.3\tCusto: ");
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");

      // Adiciona informações antes da tabela
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("365 x nº vezes por dia / nº comprimidos na caixa. 52 semanas = (364 dias) / semanas do ciclo. Nº de ciclos no ano x qtdade inteira (com sobra/com o descarte) de medicação necessário por ciclo. Nºs sempre arredondados para cima. Obs.: checar se a estabilidade da reconstituição fármaco permite aproveitamento de sobras de um ciclo para o outro. Cálculo diverso nesse caso! Havendo possibilidade de reaproveitamento = 52 / nºs de ciclos x qtdade fracionada para dose correta.")
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(10).setFontFamily("Arial");

      corpo = adiciona_tabela(corpo, abaTecnologia);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("* Valor unitário considerado a partir de consulta de preço da tabela CMED. Preço máximo de venda ao governo (PMVG) no Rio Grande do Sul (ICMS 17%). O PMVG é o resultado da aplicação do Coeficiente de Adequação de Preços (CAP) sobre o Preço Fábrica – PF, PMVG = PF*(1-CAP). O CAP, regulamentado pela Resolução nº. 3, de 2 de março de 2011, é um desconto mínimo obrigatório a ser aplicado sempre que forem realizadas vendas de medicamentos constantes do rol anexo ao Comunicado nº 15, de 31 de agosto de 2017 - Versão Consolidada ou para atender ordem judicial. Conforme o Comunicado CMED nº 5, de 21 de dezembro de 2020, o CAP é de 21,53%. Alguns medicamentos possuem isenção de ICMS para aquisição por órgãos da Administração Pública Direta Federal, Estadual e Municipal, conforme Convênio ICMS nº 87/02, sendo aplicado o benefício quando cabível.\n").setFontSize(8).setFontSize(9).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
      // Coloca texto abaixo da tabela de custo
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph(abaTecnologia.getRange(26, 1).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);

      // Adiciona item 6.4 a 6.6
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("6.4\tConclusão técnica: " + abaTecnologia.getRange(27, 2).getValue() + "\n");
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var titulo = corpo.appendParagraph("6.5\tJustificativa: ");
      titulo.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph(abaTecnologia.getRange(54, 1).getValue() + abaTecnologia.getRange(29, 1).getValue() + "\n");
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);

      // Adiciona item 6.6
      var titulo = corpo.appendParagraph("6.6\tReferências: ");
      titulo.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph(abaTecnologia.getRange(32, 1).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);

      // Adiciona item 7
      var titulo = corpo.appendParagraph("7\tEmissão");
      titulo.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setBold(true);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("7.1\tPrimeira emissão de nota técnica sobre tecnologia de saúde associada ao CID: " + abaTecnologia.getRange(35, 2).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("7.2\tNecessidade de interação com a parte autora: " + abaTecnologia.getRange(61, 2).getValue());
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("7.3\tProfissional da saúde responsável pela nota técnica: ");
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("7.4\tProfissional de saúde revisor: ");
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("7.5\tInstituição responsável: TelessaúdeRS-UFRGS");
      texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
      var texto = corpo.appendParagraph("7.6    Declaração de conflito de interesses: os autores da nota técnica declaram não possuir qualquer interesse na prescrição do tratamento postulado pela demanda e tampouco mantém vínculo, incluindo patrocínios diversos, com a indústria que o produz ou com o médico que assiste à parte autora.");
      
texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial").setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);

// Saving and closing as Tanaike suggested
document.saveAndClose();

// I guess this content variable is saving everything else in the document as well
var content = Docs.Documents.get(id).body.content.pop();

// Callling the function with the document id and the new content variable (as the new suggestion by @Tanaike)
createFootnoteWithText(id, content.startIndex + text.length);;
```

These are the functions to insert the footnote:

```
// This function was edited as suggested by @Tanaike
function createFootnoteWithText(id, bodyIndex) {
  text = 'Entendemos que o termo imediato é o definidor principal desse conceito. Nessas situações o paciente não pode esperar nem mesmo alguns poucos dias, sendo necessário seu encaminhamento imediato para uma emergência médica e, se houver indicação, proceder à internação hospitalar.';
  const createFootnoteReplies = createFootnote_(bodyIndex, id);
  if (createFootnoteReplies && createFootnoteReplies.replies.length) {
    const reply = createFootnoteReplies.replies[0];
    return appendTextTo_(text, reply.createFootnote.footnoteId, id);
  }
  return {issue: 'no replies', createFootnoteReplies };
}

function createFootnote_(bodyIndex, id) {
  return Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(
    {
      requests: {
        createFootnote: {
          location: {
            index: bodyIndex,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    id
  );
}

function appendTextTo_(text, segmentId = "", id) {
  return Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(
    {
      requests: {
        insertText: {
          text,
          endOfSegmentLocation: {
            segmentId,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    id
  );
}
```

After the new modifications suggested by @Tanaike the document appears like this (as you can see the footnote got inserted in the last page):

[image: document as the output of the code]

Comment: Alas, looks like Docs still have no such obvious option.

Comment: Are you trying to insert the footnote into a header, footer or footnote? https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#createfootnoterequest

Comment: @FernandoLara! Thanks for your attention! I am trying to insert the footnote as a footnote.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From your showing script, how about using `saveAndClose()` as follows? I thought that in your flow, in order to retrieve the appended paragraph by Document service (DocumentApp), it is required to save the document. By saving the document, the value of `bodyIndex` can be used for the middle of the paragraph.

```js
function createFootnoteWithText(id, bodyIndex) {
  text = 'Entendemos que o termo imediato é o definidor principal desse conceito. Nessas situações o paciente não pode esperar nem mesmo alguns poucos dias, sendo necessário seu encaminhamento imediato para uma emergência médica e, se houver indicação, proceder à internação hospitalar.';
  const createFootnoteReplies = createFootnote_(bodyIndex, id);
  if (createFootnoteReplies && createFootnoteReplies.replies.length) {
    const reply = createFootnoteReplies.replies[0];
    return appendTextTo_(text, reply.createFootnote.footnoteId, id);
  }
  return { issue: 'no replies', createFootnoteReplies };
}

function createFootnote_(bodyIndex, id) {
  return Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(
    {
      requests: {
        createFootnote: {
          location: {
            index: bodyIndex,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    id
  );
}

function appendTextTo_(text, segmentId = "", id) {
  return Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(
    {
      requests: {
        insertText: {
          text,
          endOfSegmentLocation: {
            segmentId,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    id
  );
}

// Please run this script.
function main() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var id = doc.getId();
  var corpo = doc.getBody();
  var urgencia = "sample";
  // Appending the text do the document body
  var text = "4.8\tUrgência";
  var texto = corpo.appendParagraph(text + " (conforme definição da Resolução CFM nº 1451/95: ocorrência imprevista de agravo à saúde com ou sem risco potencial de vida, cujo portador necessita de assistência médica imediata): " + urgencia);
  texto.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.NORMAL).setFontSize(12).setFontFamily("Arial");
  doc.saveAndClose();
  var content = Docs.Documents.get(id).body.content.pop();

  // Callling the function with the document id
  createFootnoteWithText(id, content.startIndex + text.length);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this modified script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [saveAndClose()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#saveandclose)

Comment: ! Thank you so much for your help. I made the modifications that you suggested, but my document is very big (it has a front page and multiple tables) and  when I run your code the footnote is being inserted in the front page (I will edit my question to show how the page is being saved).

Comment: @Frederico Falcetta Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your reply, I thought that the reason of your issue is due to that your document has already had the texts. For this, I updated my proposed script. Could you pleasec confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: you are a life saver! I think I am getting there, but now the footnote is in the end of the document. I am going to edit my question with more of my code to make it clearer.

Comment: @Frederico Falcetta Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new issue from `After the new modifications suggested by @Tanaike the document appears like this (as you can see the footnote got inserted in the last page):`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? In your showing script, the text is put to the last of the document body. I followed your this direction.

Comment: Thank you for replying @Tanaike! I uploaded just a fraction of my code since the code is very big (400 lines approx.). The footnote has to be inserted in the middle of the document. I have lots of information before the footnote and then lots of information after the footnote.

Comment: @Frederico Falcetta Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `The footnote has to be inserted in the middle of the document. I have lots of information before the footnote and then lots of information after the footnote.`, I cannot imagine your situation. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the simple sample input and output situation you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your situation. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Thanks again for replying @Tanaike! Sorry for taking so long to respond. We had a newborn baby ad I didn't have the time to reply. I'm putting all the code from my function so that I can be clearer.

Comment: @Frederico Falcetta Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your updated script and my proposed script. Can I ask you about the detail of it?